# AngularJs ng-show for when an item in a list is true in one line

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a condition where basically what I want to do is if there is a bool set to true I want to toggle.  But the bool is attached to items in a list. Take a look:

```
<div ng-repeat="step in progress.steps">
    <div ng-if="step.criticalError">
    </div>
</div>
```

Simple enough.

**Now the problem!**

Take a step backward to the containing divs. I want to handle a scenario like this..Have 3 divs.  Only 2 will show at a time. The factor that determines that is the criticalError. It is an all or nothing, so if one trips as a critical error then all the steps show on top; otherwise they will all show below if there is no critical.  So like this.

```
<div ng-show="containsCriticalError"></div>
<div>Always shows.</div>
<div ng-show="!containsCriticalError"></div>
```

Or would you have to iterate through the list, is it possible to stop an ng-repeat once a condition is met?

Comment: You can limit an ng-repeat, but you cannot do a 'classical' break once you've started one.

Comment: I misread your question. Updated the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
<div ng-show="!containsCriticalError">Always shows.</div>
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="step in progress.steps">
        <div ng-if="step.criticalError">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-show="containsCriticalError">Always shows.</div>
```

Or just move the div with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit funky, but it works

```
<div ng-repeat="step in progress.steps"
     ng-init="show = !step.criticalError && ($$prevSibling || {show: true}).show">
    <div ng-if="show">
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

I misread the question. The above approach displays only the steps above the first criticalError.

Here's what I think the OP is requesting:

```
<div ng-if="!show.v">Always shows...</div>
<div ng-init="show = {v: false}">
  <div ng-repeat="step in steps" 
       ng-init="show.v = step.criticalError || show.v">

  </div>  
</div>
<div ng-if="show.v">Always shows...</div>
```